# Ansible yum update then email me the results

Tags: email, yum, ansible, grep

Writing a playbook to perform yum updates and then get an email from each server. I'd like the email to contain the *changed* contents of yum.log.

IOW, I want the results of:

```
grep [today's date] /var/log/yum.log
```

to be emailed from each server.

I tried using `shell:` to perform the grep then send the mail :

```
    shell: grep '^`date +"%b %d"`' /var/log/yum.log | mail -s "updates applied to `hostname -s` today" updatereports@mydomain.com
```

It just sends a blank email.

Also tried using the mail function but am struggling to dump a multi-line variable into the body of the message:

```
- name: test result
  ignore_errors: yes
  shell: grep "`date '+%b %d'`" /var/log/messages
  register: updated

- name: mail result
  mail:
    to: updatereports@mydomain.com
    subject: "updates applied to {{ ansible_hostname }} today"
    body: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ updated.results|map(attribute='stdout_lines')|list }}"
  when: updated.stdout
```

It also sends, but prints the timestamp then generates a line of errors for each matched line in yum.log:

```
['Sep 12 16:15:28 host-ng ansible-command: Invoked with warn=True executable=None _uses_shell=True _raw_params=grep "`date \'+%b %d\'`" /var/log/messages | tail removes=None creates=None chdir=None'
```

I found that fancy `results|map` code [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/QUugEQRZT-g) but don't understand it enough  to work without errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not certain if it is your only problem, but one problem is that your `with_items` is indented incorrectly.  The `with_items` belongs to a task, not the `mail`.

```
- name: mail result
  mail:
    to: updatereports@mydomain.com
    subject: "updates applied to {{ ansible_hostname }} today"
    body: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ updated.results|map(attribute='stdout_lines')|list }}"
  when: updated.stdout
```

I am not really sure if you need the `with_items` at all in this case though.  You need to use `with_items` when you are looping over a collection of something.

Since I don't know the answer, if I where in your shoes I would simply start with some simple debug tasks instead of the mail.  Once you see the results of the debug it should be a lot easier to see what you need to do.

```
- name: mail result
  debug:
    msg: "{{ updated }}"
- name: mail result
  debug:
    msg: ""{{ updated.results|map(attribute='stdout_lines')|list }}""
```

Comment: good catch with the formatting and thanks for explaining!

Comment: The debug tips helped. It's working in the debug msg when I remove the fancy code above and just dump `updated.stdout_lines`, but when it mails the result the lines are all mashed together. Is there a way to print stdout_lines with carriage returns?

Comment: Maybe try using the `updated.stdout` instead of `stdout.stdout_lines`.  The stdout_lines is a list of the lines split on the line feeds.  I think the stdout is the entire output.  See the 'Return values' section of the shell module.  http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/shell_module.html  I bet there some way to add line breaks with jinja, but I am also relatively new to ansible so I don't know how yet.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for sharing your ideas @Zoredache! This works just fine:

```
- name: test result
  ignore_errors: yes
  shell: grep "`date '+%b.%d'`" /var/log/yum.log
  register: updated

- name: mail result
  mail:
    to: updatereports@mydomain.com
    subject: "updates applied to {{ ansible_hostname }} today"
    body: "{{ updated.stdout }}"
  when: updated.stdout
```

**Update**: I spoke too soon! I was testing it by grepping `/var/log/messages` but when I perform the grep on `/var/log/yum.log` the output is mashed together again without any linebreaks.**